# Retrieving Super property of a object property in OWL Api 4

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

I have a object property Car and its sub property as Ferrari. I want to get super property i.e Car for Ferrari with owl api 4. I can get sub-properties of a property but not super property. Is there any api that i am missing ?

Comment: Remember that a given property can have more than one super property (that may or may not affect your use case).

Comment: Does [getSuperProperties](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLPropertyExpression.html#getSuperProperties%28org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology%29) work?

Comment: Can you show the code for getting sub properties?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Answer that i have posted gives me the immediate super property and that's what i am looking for...But i didnt like my way of iterating over all the object properties and checking whether its subproperty matches with the current sub property and conclude the give property as super property.

Comment: @Ignazio I have posted the answer..you can check that code...please suggest if any other better way you might know....As i didn't liked the idea of iterating over all the object properties.

Answer (score 2):

If the sub property relationship is directly asserted, you can use the [OWLOntology::getObjectSubPropertyAxiomsForSubProperty](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4_1_0/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLAxiomIndex.html#getObjectSubPropertyAxiomsForSubProperty-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectPropertyExpression-) method.

Example:

```
OWLOntology o = ...
OWLObjectProperty p = ...
o.getObjectSubPropertyAxiomsForSubProperty(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do this in following way :-

```
Set<OWLObjectProperty> props = ont.getObjectPropertiesInSignature();
            for (OWLObjectProperty p : props) {
                HashSet<OWLSubObjectPropertyOfAxiom> subPropertySet =   (HashSet)ont.getObjectSubPropertyAxiomsForSuperProperty(p);
                for (OWLSubObjectPropertyOfAxiom subPropAxiom : subPropertySet) {
                    OWLObjectPropertyExpression subObjectProperty = subPropAxiom.getSubProperty();
                    if (subObjectProperty.getNamedProperty().getIRI().equals(relationIRI)) {
                        d.setDerivedFrom(p.getIRI().getShortForm());

                    }
                }
            }
```

If there is better way to do this please let me know.

Comment: Simon's answer below takes advantage of an internal index, so it's going to be faster.

Comment: @Ignazio i am not looking for subproperty of a property...I am asking for superproperty for a given property.

Comment: Yes - in Simon's answer, the method reference says "bySubProperty". The resulting axioms will have the input property as sub property. To get the super properties, iterate through the axioms and collect the super property for each axiom. I'll extend the example.

Comment: @Ignazio I was busy doing other code...so couldn't reply..Thanks for help...Extended code i have posted as the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator<OWLSubObjectPropertyOfAxiom> subItr = ont.getObjectSubPropertyAxiomsForSubProperty(factory.getOWLObjectProperty(relationIRI)).iterator();
            while (subItr.hasNext()) {
                OWLSubObjectPropertyOfAxiom subPropAxiom = subItr.next();
                d.setDerivedFrom(subPropAxiom.getSuperProperty().getNamedProperty().getIRI().getShortForm());
            }
```

Just adding to simon's answer...this works fine for me....